# For Loop causing error when asked to loop more than 10 times

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, google-apps-script

I have the following HTML:

```
<form id = "sortable" class="ui-state">
    <div class = "sortableItem day">Monday</div> <!-- 0 -->
    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 1 -->
        <span id="result1"></span>
        <span id="address1" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact1" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel1" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 2 -->
        <span id="result2"></span>
        <span id="address2" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact2" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel2" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 3 -->
        <span id="result3"></span>
        <span id="address3" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact3" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel3" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 4 -->
        <span id="result4"></span>
        <span id="address4" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact4" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel4" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 5 -->
        <span id="result5"></span>
        <span id="address5" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact5" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel5" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>


    <div class = "sortableItem day">Tuesday</div> <!-- 6 -->
    <div class = "sortableItem day hidden"></div> <!-- 7 -->

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 8 -->
        <span id="result6"></span>
        <span id="address6" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact6" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel6" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 9 -->
        <span id="result7"></span>
        <span id="address7" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact7" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel7" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!--10 -->
        <span id="result8"></span>
        <span id="address8" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact8" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel8" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 11 -->
        <span id="result9"></span>
        <span id="address9" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact9" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel9" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 12 -->
        <span id="result10"></span>
        <span id="address10" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact10" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel10" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 13 -->
        <span id="result11"></span>
        <span id="address11" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact11" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel11" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>


    <div class = "sortableItem day">Wednesday</div> <!-- 14 -->
    <div class = "sortableItem day hidden"></div> <!-- 15 -->

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 16 -->
        <span id="result12"></span>
        <span id="address12" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact12" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel12" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default">  <!-- 17 -->
        <span id="result13"></span>
        <span id="address13" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact13" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel13" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 18 -->
        <span id="result14"></span>
        <span id="address14" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact14" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel14" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 19 -->
        <span id="result15"></span>
        <span id="address15" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact15" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel15" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 20 -->
        <span id="result16"></span>
        <span id="address16" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact16" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel16" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>


    <div class = "sortableItem day">Thursday</div> <!-- 21 -->
    <div class = "sortableItem day hidden"></div> <!-- 22 -->

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 23 -->
        <span id="result17"></span>
        <span id="address17" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact17" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel17" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 24 -->
        <span id="result18"></span>
        <span id="address18" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact18" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel18" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 25 -->
        <span id="result19"></span>
        <span id="address19" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact19" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel19" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 26 -->
        <span id="result20"></span>
        <span id="address20" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact20" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel20" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 27 -->
        <span id="result21"></span>
        <span id="address21" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact21" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel21" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>


    <div class = "sortableItem day">Friday</div> <!-- 28 -->
    <div class = "sortableItem day hidden"></div> <!-- 29 -->

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 30 -->
        <span id="result22"></span>
        <span id="address22" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact22" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel22" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 31 -->
        <span id="result23"></span>
        <span id="address23" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact23" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel23" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 32 -->
        <span id="result24"></span>
        <span id="address24" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact24" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel24" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>

    <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default"> <!-- 33 -->
        <span id="result25"></span>
        <span id="address25" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="contact25" class="hidden"></span>
        <span id="tel25" class="hidden"></span>
    </div>
```

I need to create an array containing the values in each of the spans where ID is `"result"` + a number.

This is the loop I wrote:

```
   $("#clickMe").click(function() {
     var childElements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33];

     var hotelNames = [];
     for(var i = 0; i < childElements.length; i++) {
        hotelNames.push(sortable.children[childElements[i]].children[0].innerHTML);
     }
     alert(hotelNames)
   })
```

And in my console I get the following error:

[image]

I replaced the `childElements.length` with a number as follows:

```
     for(var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
       hotelNames.push(sortable.children[childElements[i]].children[0].innerHTML);
     }
```

And I get the same error again.

However, when I put a value that is no greater than 10 it works:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   hotelNames.push(sortable.children[childElements[i]].children[0].innerHTML);
 }
```

Result:

[image]

As soon as I go to '11' the error occurs.

I'm sure I'm doing something obviously wrong but I cannot for the life of me figure this out..

Comment: Providing a full example of your code would be helpful. Where is the word "Hotel" coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are saying, it works for `i<10`, so let's see for when `i=10`.

```
var childElements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, ...];
// ...............i = 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8   9   ^
```

When `i=11` `childElements[10]` gives the value of `15`.

For the below code,

`sortable.children[childElements[i]].children[0].innerHTML`

=> `sortable.children[childElements[11]].children[0].innerHTML`

=> `sortable.children[15].children[0].innerHTML`

Now looking at your HTML, `sortable.children[15]` is:

`<div class = "sortableItem day hidden"></div> <!-- 15 -->`

If you look at it, it doesn't have any children, so `sortable.children[15].children[0]` will give `undefined`. And when you try to access any key on `undefined` in JavaScript, it though's error.

---

You can either put a check before trying to access the value or put it in a try catch block.

```
// Check before accessing innerHTML value
if(sortable.children[childElements[i]].children[0]){
   hotelNames.push(sortable.children[childElements[i]].children[0].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vatz88, I think I had been staring at it for so long I couldn't see the errors anymore! But yes, you are right that my childElements array was just wrong! All sorted now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to see whether `.children` has length before trying to access `.children[0]`. In cases like `<div class = "sortableItem day hidden"></div> <!-- 7 -->`, that `div` has no children. So just add in a check before your push, like:

```
var elem = sortable.children[childElements[i]]
if (elem && elem.children && elem.children.length) hotelNames.push(...
```

Arguably, a better way would be to use `querySelectorAll` to get only the nodes that you want.

```
var sortableItems = sortable.querySelectorAll('.sortableItem > span:first-child')
for(var i = 0; i < sortableItems.length; i++){
  hotelNames.push(sortableItems[i].innerHTML)
}
alert(hotelNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do it using `map`

```
$("#clickMe").click(function() {

  var childElements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33];

  var hotelNames = childElements.map(i => $('#result'+i).text());

  alert(hotelNames)
})
```